# When does Excel surround sheet names with single quotes in workbook.xml (or other xml) files?

Tags: xml, excel, openxml

I have an .xlsx file that opens in Excel. However, if I remove the single quotes around the sheet name (which does not contain spaces) in the defined names field in workbook.xml, Excel repairs the file by removing that defined name.

Can anyone tell the criteria when do we have to surround the sheetname with single quotes?

The files are present here :
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/eziv9jlbpsppw83/AACwurdX_aOhbK4R06FRizd3a?dl=0

00007113-ENGLISH_original.xlsx - Opens in Mac Excel 2011

00007113-ENGLISH_exported.xlsx - Does not open (Repair dialog)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems not to be a general description.

But I can tell you why `Excel` surrounds the sheet name `RC2ACQuotas` with quotes in the reference `'RC2ACQuotas'!$A$1:$Q$213`. It is because `RC2` also is a cell reference in `R1C1` notation. It means `R`ow`C`olumn`2` = this row column 2.

This seems not to be consequent since `Excel` surrounds a sheet name `A123` with quotes but `A123Test` not. But sheet names starting with a cell reference in `R1C1` notation will always be surrounded.

Comment: Makes sense. Although I guess this is not in OOXML spec, right ? I tried to find any spec for this by Excel or OOXML but wasn't able to.

Comment: Right, there seems not to be any specification for this. And as I said it is not consequent. `A123Test` will not be surrounded with quotes while `RC123Test` will. But both are not really to be confused to be cell references. Best approach will be always using single quotes around sheet names since they do not hurt if present, only if not.

Answer (score 12):

Excel will quote the worksheet name if any of the following is true:

- It contains any space or punctuation characters, such as  `()$,;-{}"'（）【】“”‘’%…` and many more
- It is a valid cell reference in `A1` notation, e.g. `B1048576` is quoted, `B1048577` is not
- It is a valid cell reference in `R1C1` notation, e.g. `RC`, `RC2`, `R5C`, `R-4C`, `RC-8`, `R`, `C`
- It starts with a non-letter, e.g. `99`, `1.5`, `12a`, `a`

Excel will *not* quote worksheet names if they only contain non-punctuation, non-letter characters in non-initial positions. For example, `a` remains unquoted.

In addition, if a worksheet name *contains* single quotes, these will be doubled up within the name itself. For example, the sheet name `a'b'c` becomes `'a''b''c'`.

(There may be more scenarios — please edit this Community Wiki answer if more are found)

Comment: adding:  worksheet name will also be quoted, if it contains the ! character.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and found that the reason is as follows
(a) Sheet names that have spaces get surrounded by the quotes
(b) Sheet names that use underscore or simply do not have spaces are not