# ISREF + INDIRECT does not work on one particular sheetname

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've created sheets in an Excel Workbook.
I am testing if Worksheets exist using ISREF and INDIRECT.
Sheets will be named A01, A02 etc... B01 etc... C01 etc... D01 etc
This works, except with the sheetname C01. I'ts driving me nuts.
I've tested this on different PC's and in office365 (browser excel).

[I've included the file here.](http://www.filedropper.com/testnameexists)

I've added the file. Would anyone know what the problem is?
[image: Image (dutch, ISVERWIJZING means ISREF]

Comment: Can you check whether you are not having a space before `C01` on the Sheet's name?

Comment: I did and there isn't.

Comment: Are you 100% sure?

Comment: Could there be a space after `C01` in cell B1 then? Perhaps `CLEAN(TRIM())` it. You could try `=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)` on sheet `C01` and look at what the value is in the cell then evaluate that  `=B1=[cell with formula]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the language version of `Excel` Sheet names like "C01" or "R01" may be in conflict with `R1C1` notation.

This conflict can be avoided by putting sheet names in single qoutes while used in `INDIRECT`:

```
=ISREF(INDIRECT("'"&B1&"'!A1"))
```

There seems not to be a consequent rule which sheet names leads to such problems. This [When does Excel surround sheet names with single quotes in workbook.xml (or other xml) files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41677779/when-does-excel-surround-sheet-names-with-single-quotes-in-workbook-xml-or-othe) also may be related.

So best approach will be always using single quotes around sheet names since they do not hurt if present, only if not.

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you so much! C01 / R01 confilct makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

> Probably an artificial space, either in the Cell or in Sheetname!

Also, change the formula like so to minimize the chance of extra whitespace messing the formula up. Alternatively your excel sheet could be auto-detecting R1C1 style for some unknown reason. To enforce A1 Style, add `TRUE` to the optional argument of your `INDIRECT` function. So the formula would look like:

`=ISREF(INDIRECT(TRIM(B1) & "!A1", TRUE))`

Works fine for me

[image]

Comment: Could you tell me something more about artificial spaces? There is nog space in cell or sheetname. Trim does not work for me. A few questions because this is getting weird. Did you open the file? Did it return true right away or just after the trim? Did you see any spaces anywhere?

Comment: @Jan-Willem can't download the file directly because I'm at work. I did however re-create the Workbook with the same sheetnames and data. So if this doesn't work, this must only mean there must be an artificial space in your Seetname, alternatively your `INDIRECT` function could be confusing the referencing style (R1C1). Actually let me edit my answer accordingly, to make sure it's enforced. If this doesn't work, that must only mean there is something wrong with the Sheet name

Comment: Also to answer your question about whitespaces. The trim function removes any extra (leading and trailing) whitespaces of the string, in other words. if your cell B1 contained text `"  Hello  "` then the function `=TRIM(B1)` would result in `"Hello"` *(without quotation marks obviously)*. This however doesn't *(and cannot)* influence the sheetname itself, which can't be referenced via text directly (hence the indirect function as well) - that needs to be checked manually

Comment: Hi. Spaces had nothing to do with it, it was indeed a language reference style conflict. See the accepted answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51038981/3671890

Comment: @Jan-Willem Hi, check my edited answer aswell, see if it works (it hopefully should) as the `TRUE` optional argument in `INDIRECT` should enfore A1 referencing